# Group string values in one list based on values in another two lists using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex, list

I have three lists:

```
a = ['AFM_123_H2O_56', '345_FM_CO2', 'H6C6_AFM_test', 'dio_CO2_FM', 'check_H2O_FM', 'sample_FM_H6C6', 'AFM_67_H2O']
condition1 = ['H2O', 'CO2', 'H6C6']
condition2 = ['FM', 'AFM']
```

Output should look like this:

```
c = [['AFM_123_H2O_56', 'AFM_67_H2O'], #all strings containing H2O and AFM
      ['check_H2O_FM'],                #all strings containing H2O and FM
      ['345_FM_CO2', 'dio_CO2_FM'],    #all strings containing CO2 and FM
      ['H6C6_AFM_test'],               #all strings containing H6C6 and AFM
      ['sample_FM_H6C6']]              #all strings containing H6C6 and FM
```

Or if using pandas dataframe then output should look like this:

```
H2O_AFM       ['AFM_123_H2O_56', 'AFM_67_H2O']
H2O_FM        ['check_H2O_FM']
CO2_FM        ['345_FM_CO2', 'dio_CO2_FM']
H6C6_AFM      ['H6C6_AFM_test']
H6C6_FM       ['sample_FM_H6C6']
```

I need to group elements in "a" list based on the values in "condition1" and "condition2"  lists and save the result to the third list. I know how to do it with for loop, but I guess using pandas there might be better solution.

I know only how to do it for one list condition:

```
pattern = '(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, condition1))
series_files = pd.Series(a)
df_grouped_files = series_files.groupby(series_files.str.extract(pattern, expand=False), sort=False).agg(list)
```

But I don't know how to do it for the cross product from two list conditions.

Comment: Could you explain the logic? It's not obvious from the inputs and output.

Comment: In the pandas dataframe, the first column appears to be the cross product of `condition1` and `condition2`. You can use `itertools.product()` to generate that. Then for each pair, you can use the `in` operator to find elements of `a` that match both.

Comment: I know only how to do it for one list condition:
pattern = '(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, condition1))

Comment: Turn the conditions into a dataframe containing the cross product of all the conditions. Merge that with a dataframe containing `a`, using `.str.contains()` in the joining condition.

Comment: Use `&` to combine the two conditions. You don't need a regular expression, just use `.str.contains()`

Comment: Put your attempt in the question, not comments.

Comment: Barmar, thank you for your suggestions, using .str.contains worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your substrings are separated by `_`, you could use `set` operations:

```
from itertools import product

s = pd.Series(a)

out = pd.Series({S: s[s.str.split('_').apply(S.issubset)].tolist()
                 for S in map(frozenset, product(condition1, condition2))
                })
```

Output:

```
(H2O, FM)                    [check_H2O_FM]
(H2O, AFM)     [AFM_123_H2O_56, AFM_67_H2O]
(CO2, FM)          [345_FM_CO2, dio_CO2_FM]
(CO2, AFM)                               []
(FM, H6C6)                 [sample_FM_H6C6]
(AFM, H6C6)                 [H6C6_AFM_test]
dtype: object
```

Alternative format for the keys:

```
out = pd.Series({'_'.join(x): s[s.str.split('_').apply(set(x).issubset)].tolist()
                 for x in product(condition1, condition2)
                })
```

Output:

```
H2O_FM                    [check_H2O_FM]
H2O_AFM     [AFM_123_H2O_56, AFM_67_H2O]
CO2_FM          [345_FM_CO2, dio_CO2_FM]
CO2_AFM                               []
H6C6_FM                 [sample_FM_H6C6]
H6C6_AFM                 [H6C6_AFM_test]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure a list is an appropriate output structure, as you can't tell which matches correspond to which conditions. A dictionary might be better. You can create that using a dictionary comprehension, using `re.search` to match conditions (surrounded by `_` or beginning/end of string) and `itertools.product` to get all the combinations of conditions:

```py
import re, itertools

a = ['AFM_123_H2O_56', '345_FM_CO2', 'H6C6_AFM_test', 'dio_CO2_FM', 'check_H2O_FM', 'sample_FM_H6C6', 'AFM_67_H2O']
condition1 = ['H2O', 'CO2', 'H6C6']
condition2 = ['FM', 'AFM']

c = { f'{c1}_{c2}' : 
     [s for s in a if re.search(fr'(^|_){c1}(_|$)', s) and re.search(fr'(^|_){c2}(_|$)', s)] 
     for c1, c2 in itertools.product(condition1, condition2) 
}
```

Output:

```
{
  'H2O_FM': ['check_H2O_FM'],
  'H2O_AFM': ['AFM_123_H2O_56', 'AFM_67_H2O'],
  'CO2_FM': ['345_FM_CO2', 'dio_CO2_FM'],
  'CO2_AFM': [],
  'H6C6_FM': ['sample_FM_H6C6'],
  'H6C6_AFM': ['H6C6_AFM_test']
}
```

If you do want just a list, use `list(c.values())` (which you can `filter` to remove empty lists if desired):

```
[['check_H2O_FM'], ['AFM_123_H2O_56', 'AFM_67_H2O'], ['345_FM_CO2', 'dio_CO2_FM'], [], ['sample_FM_H6C6'], ['H6C6_AFM_test']]
```

If you want a dataframe, it's easy enough to convert:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(zip(c.keys(), c.values()))
```

Output:

```
          0                             1
0    H2O_FM                [check_H2O_FM]
1   H2O_AFM  [AFM_123_H2O_56, AFM_67_H2O]
2    CO2_FM      [345_FM_CO2, dio_CO2_FM]
3   CO2_AFM                            []
4   H6C6_FM              [sample_FM_H6C6]
5  H6C6_AFM               [H6C6_AFM_test]
```

Comment: The question specifically asks for a pandas solution. They said they know how to do it with ordinary loops.

Comment: @Barmar The question says "Output should look like this" with a list (which I think I've improved upon), and then "*Or* if using pandas...".